# Animation stalling when sound is played

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When I play a sound, usually the first time but sometimes at the succeeding times as well, the current playing animation of my app stalls.

I stored all my Sound objects in static variables in a class called Jukebox. Anywhere in my code I need to play a sound I call a static method of Jukebox called playSfx().

Here's the relevant code:

```
public static function
playSfx( snd:Sound, vol:Number = 1 ):void
{
    _channelSfx = snd.play();
    _transform = _channelSfx.soundTransform;
    _transform.volume = vol;
    _channelSfx.soundTransform = _transform;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: There's not enough here to answer your question adequately (where's the animation object you spoke of?).  However, be advised, you need to recreate the sound object for any new sound files you want to play on it.  This is a common pitfall when using sound.

Comment: Whatever is animating on the stage stalls. Yes I am already doing that. It feels like the sound is loading when it's first called hence the stalling? But I have a pre-loader in place.